# What is the value of arg in Task.Factory.StartNew

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have `Task.Factory.StartNew` in C# code with `args` argument. I am not quite understand what value will `arg` be. So what value will `args` be and how the value is determined?

```
int count = table.Rows.Count;

    Dictionary<int, string> expDic = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();

    for (int f = 0; f < count; f++)
    {
        DataRow tempformula = table.Rows[f];
        string formulaSymbol = Convert.ToString(tempformula[Common.Systems.Sustainability.Constants.IndicatorFormula.Symbol]);


        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action<object>((args) => {
            int i = (int)args;

            _sem.Wait();
            StringBuilder expression = new StringBuilder(1024);

            DataRow formula = table.Rows[i];
            int indID = Convert.ToInt32(formula[Common.Systems.Sustainability.Constants.IndicatorFormula.IndicatorID]);
            int sequence = Convert.ToInt32(formula[Common.Systems.Sustainability.Constants.IndicatorFormula.Sequence]);
            int? referenceIndID = Common.Util.TryToConvertToInt32(formula, Common.Systems.Sustainability.Constants.IndicatorFormula.ReferenceIndicatorID);
            decimal? val = Common.Util.TryToConvertToDecimal(formula, Common.Systems.Sustainability.Constants.IndicatorFormula.Value);
            string symbol = Convert.ToString(formula[Common.Systems.Sustainability.Constants.IndicatorFormula.Symbol]);
            string formulaOutputUnit = Convert.ToString(formula[Common.Systems.Sustainability.Constants.Indicator.Unit]);

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(callerAcceptedUnit)) // added by HC on 2016-05-27
            {
                formulaOutputUnit = callerAcceptedUnit;
            }
            if (referenceIndID == null)
            {
                if (val == null)
                {
                    DataSet indicator = GetIndicatorByIDFromCache(companyID, indID); // added by HC on 2017-05-12, for performance tuning.
                                                                                     //using (DataSet indicator = indicatorMgr.GetIndicatorByID(companyID, indID))
                    {
                        DataRow dr = indicator.Tables[0].Rows[0];
                        int indicatorType = Convert.ToInt32(dr[Common.Systems.Sustainability.Constants.Indicator.IndicatorType]);
                        if (indicatorType == (int)Common.Systems.Sustainability.Constants.IndicatorTypes.Currency
                            || indicatorType == (int)Common.Systems.Sustainability.Constants.IndicatorTypes.Numeric)
                        {
                            decimal? total = SumTotal(companyID, indID, indicatorType, fromDate, toDate, formulaOutputUnit, callerIndicatorID, breakToMonthly, specifiedLocations, approvalStatus
                                , usageDataSet, interval
                                , indicatorIDsChain
                                , allowNull
                                );
                            expression.Append(total.ToString());
                        }
                        else if (symbol == "+"
                        || symbol == "-"
                        || symbol == "*"
                        || symbol == "/")
                        {
                            expression.Append(symbol);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    expression.Append(val.ToString());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                string exp = GetExpression(companyID, fromDate, toDate, referenceIndID.Value.ToString(), indID.ToString(), formulaOutputUnit, breakToMonthly, specifiedLocations, approvalStatus
                    , usageDataSet, interval
                    , indicatorIDsChain
                    );
                //expression.Append(exp);
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    // fault tolerance, for in-case users assigned symbol in the last line of formula
                    if (exp.EndsWith("+")
                        || exp.EndsWith("-")
                        || exp.EndsWith("*")
                        || exp.EndsWith("/"))
                    {
                        exp = exp.Substring(0, exp.Length - 1);
                    }
                    object result = dt.Compute(exp, "");
                    expression.Append(result);
                }
            } // end if (referenceIndID == null)...

            if ("IF".Equals(symbol, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                || "THEN".Equals(symbol, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                || "ELSE IF".Equals(symbol, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                || "ELSE".Equals(symbol, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                || ">".Equals(symbol, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                || ">=".Equals(symbol, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                || "=".Equals(symbol, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                || "<=".Equals(symbol, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                || "<".Equals(symbol, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                )
            {
                //--------------------------------------------------------
                // Begin, added by HC on 2016-12-14
                //        as requested by CQS users, add "IF" statement for GRI indicators
                string exp = HandleIFCondition(table, i, companyID, fromDate, toDate, indicatorIDs, callerIndicatorID, callerAcceptedUnit, breakToMonthly, specifiedLocations, approvalStatus, usageDataSet, interval, indicatorIDsChain);
                expression.Append(exp);
                // End, added by HC on 2016-12-14
                //--------------------------------------------------------

                // Find End if, added by Alex Poon on 20190306
                int ifIndex = i;
                for (var j = ifIndex; j < count; j++)
                {
                    string endIfSymbol = Convert.ToString(table.Rows[j][Common.Systems.Sustainability.Constants.IndicatorFormula.Symbol]);

                    if ("END IF".Equals(endIfSymbol, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        i = j;
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(symbol)
                    && expression.Length > 0 // added by HC on 2016-06-24
                    )
                {
                    if (i + 1 >= count && symbol != ")")
                    {
                        // ignore the symbol
                    }
                    else if (expression.ToString() != symbol)
                    {
                        expression.Append(symbol);
                    }
                }
                else if (expression.Length == 0 && symbol == "(")
                {
                    expression.Append(symbol);
                }
                if (symbol == "days")
                {
                    // added by HC on 2017-01-23, a new requirements for calculating average values by days.
                    if (fromDate != null && toDate != null)
                    {
                        int days = toDate.Value.Subtract(fromDate.Value).Days + 1;
                        expression.Append(days);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        expression.Append(1);
                    }
                }
            } // end if ("IF".Equals(symbol, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)...

            if (expDic != null && expression != null)
            {
                expDic.Add(i, expression.ToString());
            }

            _sem.Release();

        }), f);
        taskList.Add(t);

        if ("IF".Equals(formulaSymbol, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            for (var j = f; j < count; j++)
            {
                string endIfSymbol = Convert.ToString(table.Rows[j][Common.Systems.Sustainability.Constants.IndicatorFormula.Symbol]);

                if ("END IF".Equals(endIfSymbol, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    f = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());

    List<int> keys = expDic.Keys.ToList();
    keys.Sort();
    string finalExpression = "";
    foreach (var key in keys)
    {
        finalExpression += expDic[key];
    }

    return finalExpression;
}
```

Comment: You haven't provided a complete example. If you call `TaskFactory.StartNew` with an `Action<object>`, you've got to provide a second argument which is the value which is then passed *to* that delegate.

Comment: I found that TaskFactory.StartNew is not called, it seems is just used to create a new task, so I am doubting what value will ```args``` be?

Comment: I see you've undone my careful formatting of your code, in order to add more code. *Please* use the preview to make sure you're presenting your question in as readable a form as possible. I don't see what you mean by "I found that TaskFactory.StartNew is not called" - it *is* called in the code you've shown, by `Task.Factory.StartNew`. (`Task.Factory` returns a `TaskFactory`.)

Comment: Additionally, it would really help if you'd present a [mcve] rather than nearly 200 lines of mostly-irrelevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Tasks_TaskFactory_StartNew_System_Action_System_Object__System_Object_System_Threading_CancellationToken_System_Threading_Tasks_TaskCreationOptions_System_Threading_Tasks_TaskScheduler_)

The args argument (referred to as "state" in the documentation) is a parameter you need to specify when you call to `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

> state (Object): An object containing data to be used by the action delegate.

Sample:

```
object param = somevalue;

Task.Factory.StartNew( (arg) => 
{  /* get the arg value here.*/

}, param);
```

Comment: You mean the ```param``` will be the value of ```arg```?

Comment: In the example I provided: I am sending a variable "param" to the StartNew. Once the Task is started, this value will be passed to the delegate in arg parameter. So if param = 123, then you will get this value in the delegate function in arg variable.

Comment: In your example, I see that you are passing 'f' variable to the task and the f value is loop counter. So for each task, it will have the value of the current loop state. 0,1 until count.

Answer (score 1):

`args` in your case is data that will be passed to a delegate specified by `Action<object>` parameter.

See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Tasks_TaskFactory_StartNew_System_Action_System_Object__System_Object_System_Threading_CancellationToken_System_Threading_Tasks_TaskCreationOptions_System_Threading_Tasks_TaskScheduler_).

When using overload of `StartNew` with `Action<object>`, you need to supply next argument of type `object`, which will be used in passed delegate.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew((o) => {/* 1 will be used here */}, 1, token, options, scheduler);
```